# .net 7 Isolated Azure Function Dependency Injection Fails When Deployed (Works Locally)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

EDIT :: HAVE UPDATED THE CODE SNIPPET WITH THE EXTENSION METHODS SHOWING THE ACTUAL SERVICE

I have a web api project and an isolated function project.
Both pretty much use identical DI to the point where i've extracted a few extension methods for my DI loading.

My function is triggered by a servicebus message. If I debug locally and send a message to the bus I handle it 100%. If I deploy the function and then send a message to the bus, then it dies with a DependencyInjection error where it fails to instantiate my class.

This is my message listener function.

```
    public class ProcessingAnalyseDocumentsConsumer {

    private readonly ILogger<ProcessingAnalyseDocumentsConsumer> _logger;
    private readonly FormRecogniserService _formRecogniserService;
    private readonly ReprocessEncounterService _reprocessEncounterService;
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public ProcessingAnalyseDocumentsConsumer(
        ILogger<ProcessingAnalyseDocumentsConsumer> logger,
        FormRecogniserService formRecogniserService,
        ReprocessEncounterService reprocessEncounterService,
        DataContext context) {
        _logger = logger;
        _formRecogniserService = formRecogniserService;
        _reprocessEncounterService = reprocessEncounterService;
        _context = context;
    }

    [Function("ProcessingAnalyseDocumentsConsumer")]
    public async Task RunAsync(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(Constants.QUEUES_PROCESSING_ANALYSIS_DOCUMENTS, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        ReprocessSingleDoc message) {
        
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)}");

        var item = _context.LocationCities.FirstOrDefault();
        _logger.LogInformation($"Found item in db: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)}");

    }
}
```

My Program.cs for my function looks like this

```
    var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(async (hostContext, services) => {
        var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
        var connectionString = configuration["DefaultConnection"];
        var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(dbContextOptions =>
            dbContextOptions
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(
                connectionString,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("WEBAPIPROJECTASSEMBLY"))
            );

        if (!env.IsDevelopment()) {

            services.AddAzureClients(azureClientFactoryBuilder => {
                azureClientFactoryBuilder.AddSecretClient(configuration.GetSection("KeyVault"));
            });

            Console.WriteLine("adding azure vault");
            services.AddSingleton<IKeyVaultService, KeyVaultService>();
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("adding debug vault");
            services.AddSingleton<IKeyVaultService, DebugKeyVaultService>();
        }

        await services.AddSensitiveServicesAsync(); //extension methods to add services
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); //make http context available
        services.ServiceDependencies(); //extension methods to add services
    });

await host.Build().RunAsync();
```

Here are the extension methods being called.

```
    public static async Task<IServiceCollection> AddSensitiveServicesAsync(this IServiceCollection services) {

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var keyVault = serviceProvider.GetService<IKeyVaultService>();

    if (keyVault == null) {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(keyVault));
    }

    await services.AddBlobStorage(keyVault);
    await services.AddFormRecogniserService(keyVault);
    return services;
}

public static async Task<IServiceCollection> AddBlobStorage(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IKeyVaultService keyVault) {

    var blobStorageConnectionString = await keyVault.GetSecret("blob-storage-connection");
    services.AddTransient(t => new BlobStorageService(blobStorageConnectionString));
    return services;
}

public static async Task<IServiceCollection> AddFormRecogniserService(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IKeyVaultService keyVault) {

    var secret_key = await keyVault.GetSecret("form-recogniser-key");
    var secret_endpoint = await keyVault.GetSecret("form-recogniser-endpoint");

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var blobStorage = serviceProvider.GetService<BlobStorageService>();

    if (blobStorage == null) {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(blobStorage));
    }

    services.AddTransient(t => new FormRecogniserService(secret_key, secret_endpoint, blobStorage));
    return services;
}
```

the only complicated thing is i created a debug keyvault i use for debugging and do an is environment switch - but this works locally and when i remove it - everything still breaks. also my blob storage service and form recogniser service are built using secrets retrieved from the keyvault so they're async. but i dont think this should cause any problems - it works locally and in my other projects.

dependency injection on azure always fails with the first custom service i inject regardless of what it is. i have altered services, switched them around etc etc and whatever i request its just not spinning one up. if i remove any custom services from my constructor and leave just the logger everything works fine. the custom services work 100% in my webapi project locally and on azure and in my function project locally when debugging.

> Result: Failure Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'medimore_azure.FormRecogniserService' while attempting to activate 'medimore_azure_functions.Messaging.ProcessingAnalyseDocumentsConsumer'. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DefaultFunctionActivator.CreateInstance(Type instanceType, FunctionContext context) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionActivator.cs:line 23 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 26 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 30 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88 Stack: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DefaultFunctionActivator.CreateInstance(Type instanceType, FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionActivator.cs:line 23 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(FunctionContext context) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 26 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 30 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88

Comment: Please show the code that registers `FormRecogniserService`.

Comment: @Steven i have updated the comment showing the extension methods im using to inject

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem, but calling `BuildServiceProvider` half way configuring the container is typically not a good idea. You code can certainly be rewritten so that you don't need to call `BuildServiceProvider`. Might be worth wild to check whether that solves the issue. Might it be that Azure blocks this?

Comment: turns out it was related - ended up refactoring the config section a lot and no longer needed to call buildserviceprovider inside configureservices. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As @Steven said "calling BuildServiceProvider half way configuring the container is typically not a good idea". It works on local but breaks when deployed. Refactored config section a lot and since I removed the BuildServiceProvider calls it works as expected.